# NAND2Tetris VM Translator

Tags: assembly, nand2tetris

If the pointer to the next location in the stack is raved in Ram[SP]/[0], How do I instruct the computer in hack to open the location?
I have tried

```
@0
D=M
@D
```

but it isn't opening the address in stored in Ram[0]
How do I make it access the ram address stored in Ram[0]
Thank you

Comment: What does _"opening the address"_ mean? Also, what will you be using the value of `Ram[0]` _for_ (store it somewhere else in RAM? perform a conditional jump? ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indirect through a ram location using the A/M register.

```
@SP  // loads the A register with the value SP (SP predefined to 0)
A=M  // loads the A register with the contents of MEM[0] (the stack pointer)
D=M  // loads D with the contents of MEM[Stack]
```

@D would load the A register with the contents of the symbolic location D, which will get automatically assigned by the assembler. @D (address) and D (register) are not the same thing, and for that reason, using @D is not a good idea.